# Knowing which version of a dependency posses which function

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm currently struggling with Maven, some dependencies call some others and the version does not match making one call a function that is no longer implemented or does not exist yet in the version.

Resolving those problems take me a lot of time of googling the error and checking my dependencies and a lot of testing with different versions.

Isn't there a better way to deal with that ? like a chart displaying which method are implemented in which version or something similar.

Comment: The dependency hierarchy view in Eclipse is the best way I know of. It doesn't show implemented methods, but it shows dependency versions.

Comment: Also in javadoc you should see a `@since` followed by a version for the exported classes/new methods. That should help find out which version to use. (I hope you do not have to work without documentation.)

Comment: Thanks @Gábor Bakos it helped, tought it would be usefull to know up to when a function remain like `@since 2.1` `@to 4.3`

Also is there a way to know wich dependencies are provided by each 
like if you add `hibernate-core` it will bring itself its lot of jar wich can have different specs

Comment: @Chiappero Each `@since n.x.y` is valid before `(n+1).0.0`. This is called [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). If you are lucky it will be available in version `(n+1)` and later too, but there are no compatibility requirements between major versions. (It is usually common though to remove only those things from the API that were previously deprecated.)